# Why My Logrotate Configurations Doesn't Work Correctly for MySQL-MariaDB?

Tags: 18.04, mysql, log, mariadb, logrotate

I am using an MariaDB Galera 3-Cluster and I saw that the mysql logs on Node 2 grows up to 100gb and I decided to limited these logs that will not grow a lot. I used logrotate for that, so an file with named "mysql-server" was already in directory logrotate.d and I made some changes on that file and only saved, I did not do anything else, but it is not working correctly, the logs size is again growing a lot. What should I do?

The mysql-server logrotate file was this:

```
daily
rotate 7
missingok
create 640 mysql adm
compress
sharedscripts
postrotate
 .. a default simple script...
```

I made these changes on that file:

```
rotate 1
maxsize 300M
```

How can make the logrotate that works fine and saves logs for only one day with max size 300M?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work correctly"? `maxsize 300M` doesn't mean `logrotate` will keep watching the file size all the time and rotate it as soon as it reaches 300M.

Comment: @muru I am sory may be I could not explained very well the problem, I am very beginner at logrotate and I am not sure about the correctness of configurations. What should I do to guarantee the /var/log/mysql directory will not grow upto 3gb?

Comment: The way it works is that `logrotate` is ran once a day, at which point it checks each log to see if it needs to be rotated. There's no simple way to *guarantee* that a log directory won't grow over some specified size. You could run `logrotate`every hour, maybe (or some other appropriate period). You could keep the log directory on a dedicated partition so that it doesn't affect your data or root partitions.

Comment: @muru if I change daily to hourly will my configurations be right?

Comment: No, that doesn't affect how often `logrotate` itself is run. `logrotate` is run IIRC via cron (see `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`), so that's what you'll need to change first.

Comment: @muru I made that. So what is next :)

Answer (score 0):

(Partial answer)

Some logs grow "forever" (in the absence of logrotate):  slow.log, general.log, error.log

Some logs automatically 'rotate' based on something else:  binlog* and `max_binlog_size`.

The MySQL command `FLUSH LOGS` 'rotates' all logs that it can easily and it can safely do such on.